# Bootstrap/CSS: Separate Heading and Paragraph in card body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple blog website. Each user has a Profile page that looks like this:

```
<div class="card mt-3 d-block">

<img class="rounded-circle card-image-top d-inline ml-2 mt-2 mb-2" src="{{ profile.img.url }}" alt="Profile Picture" width="200" height="200">

<div class="card-body d-inline">
    <div class="d-inline">
        <h1 class="d-inline-block card-title">{{ user.username }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="d-inline">
        <p class="card-text d-inline-block">Your bio here...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card-footer ">
    <a href="{% url 'edit-profile' %}">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary mt-3">Edit Profile Information</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Currently, it looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YElGe.jpg
I want the paragraph to be in the next line, but still next to the image. How would I do this using CSS or Bootstrap classes?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not comfortable with bootstrap...
So I did something in css

**Html code**

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="up">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="detail">

            <h1 class="d-inline-block card-title">Lorem, ipsum.</h1>

            <p class="card-text d-inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet 
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt nihil deserunt 
                consequuntur, ut laboriosam esse quo aspernatur non ducimus 
                temporibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur 
                adipisicing elit. Porro, fugiat!
           </p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="down">
        <a href="{% url 'edit-profile' %}">
            <button>
                Edit Profile Information
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>


</div>
```

**Css code**

```
.parent{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
.up{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.image{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
    
}
.image img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
}



.detail{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
.detail p{
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.down{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
button{
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
```

Out put is something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZBqc.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to have done the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="d-inline">
        <h1 class="d-inline-block card-title">{{ user.username }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="d-block">
        <p class="card-text d-inline-block">Your bio here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try flex, flex-column

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to have worked. This is what it looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/PxObdwo I just want the heading and paragraph to be next to the image, not below it.